# Stanford Core NLP Sentiment Analysis: Training with my own data

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am working on sentiment analysis using coreNLP, I have some questions about training with my own dataset, it would be a great help if someone was able to give me some idea.

According to https://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/code.html to train ones own dataset

```
java -mx8g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentTraining -numHid 25 -trainPath train.txt -devPath dev.txt -train -model model.ser.gz
```

What's the dev.txt and what data do I need to add in this file? Also I have checked class PTBTokenizer but I didn't find any text2PTB token so I can train my data?

Can someone tell me how can I train with my data?

for example test data

- "I am not sad at all" "Neutral"
- "This world is so beautiful" "Positive"
- "This world is full of bad people" "Negative"

Comment: This is a minor detail, but I believe you meant `coreNLP`

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer which works for me call

```
java -cp "*" -mx5g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.BuildBinarizedDataset -input sample.txt
```

sample.text would contain training data, 
Example
1 Today is not a good day.
3 good
3 good day 
3 a good day 
this will generate

(1 (1 Today) (1 (1 (1 (1 is) (1 not)) (3 (1 a) (3 (3 good) (1 day)))) (1 .)))

Comment: Nevermind, I found the info: https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/sentiment/BuildBinarizedDataset.html#main-java.lang.String:A- :)

Comment: buddy can you please do a comprehensive answer? the format of the sample.txt is the starting point and no documentation is making mention of it